# Getting a “You have entered too many arguments for this function” in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Trying to create a report template that says:

- If "Not Reported" then BLANK
- If "Not Detected" then "statement 1"
- If value is between 10 and 19 then "statement 2"
- If value is greater than 19 then "statement 3"

```
=IF(INDEX(Sheet1!E12:E42,MATCH(LRN,Sheet1!B12:B42,0))="Not Reported","",IF(INDEX(Sheet1!E12:E42,MATCH(LRN,Sheet1!B12:B42,0))="None Detected",CONCATENATE(Sheet1!E11," was not detected in the submitted ",INDEX(Sheet1!G12:G42,MATCH(LRN,Sheet1!B12:B42,0))," sample."),IF(AND((INDEX(Sheet1!E12:E42,MATCH(LRN,Sheet1!B12:B42,0)))>=10,(INDEX(Sheet1!E13:E42,MATCH(LRN,Sheet1!B12:B42,0)))<=19),CONCATENATE(Sheet1!E11," was detected below the level of quantitation in the submitted ",INDEX(Sheet1!G12:G42,MATCH(LRN,Sheet1!B12:B42,0))," sample.")), IF(INDEX(Sheet1!E12:E42,MATCH(LRN,Sheet1!B12:B42,0))>19,CONCATENATE("The submitted ",INDEX(Sheet1!G12:G42,MATCH(LRN,Sheet1!B12:B42,0))," sample contained ",TRUNC(INDEX(Sheet1!E12:E42,MATCH(LRN,Sheet1!B12:B42,0)),0)," ",Sheet1!G11," of ",Sheet1!E11,"."))))
```

I'm pretty new at this.  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Use Helper columns to remove some of the noise, and the repetition.  It will help find the issue.  Place your INDEX/MATCH parts in other cell and refer the those cells.

Comment: A word of advice: Creating complex applications with the wrong tools will lead to unmaintainable software. Do yourself, future you and whoever else will have to work on this a favor and use the correct tools for the job.

Comment: the info provided in the question is hard to follow, please edit it. And the formula doesn't match it ("statement 1" etc.) please change it and provide a full example.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below, you had a `,` and `)` the wrong way around. giving one of you `IFs` 3 outcomes rather than the 2.

`=IF(INDEX(Sheet1!E12:E42,MATCH(LRN,Sheet1!B12:B42,0)) = "Not Reported"    ,"",
  IF(INDEX(Sheet1!E12:E42,MATCH(LRN,Sheet1!B12:B42,0)) = "None Detected" ,CONCATENATE(Sheet1!E11," was not detected in the submitted ",INDEX(Sheet1!G12:G42,MATCH(LRN,Sheet1!B12:B42,0))," sample."),
  IF(AND((INDEX(Sheet1!E12:E42,MATCH(LRN,Sheet1!B12:B42,0)))>=10, (INDEX(Sheet1!E13:E42,MATCH(LRN,Sheet1!B12:B42,0)))<=19), CONCATENATE(Sheet1!E11," was detected below the level of quantitation in the submitted ",INDEX(Sheet1!G12:G42,MATCH(LRN,  Sheet1!B12:B42,0))," sample."), 
  IF(INDEX(Sheet1!E12:E42,MATCH(LRN,Sheet1!B12:B42,0))>19,CONCATENATE("The submitted ",INDEX(Sheet1!G12:G42,MATCH(LRN,Sheet1!B12:B42,0))," sample contained ",TRUNC(INDEX(Sheet1!E12:E42,MATCH(LRN,Sheet1!B12:B42,0)),0)," ",Sheet1!G11," of ",Sheet1!E11,"."))))`

And take Scotts advise, use helper columns to build the initial `IFs`, you can always merge them once it all works.